# Django conditional annotation: Queryset return empty if `When` condition return empty

Tags: django

I have three model `Flat`, `FlatDebit` and `FlatDebitType`

```
class Flat(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()


class FlatDebit(models.Model):
    flat = models.ForeingKey('foo.Flat', related_name='debits') 
    debit_type = models.ForeingKey('foo.FlatDebitType') 
    unpaid_amount = models.DecimalField()

class FlatDebitType(models.Model):
    TYPE1 = 1
    TYPE2 = 2
    TYPE_CHOICES = ((TYPE1, 'Type 1'), (TYPE2, 'Type 2'),)
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=TYPE1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

I want to get sum of `unpaid_amount` of some debits of each flat by `debit_type`.
Following annotation works as expected if there is debits which has `FlatDebitType` which has `TYPE2`.

```
flats = Flat.objects.all()
# <QuerySet [<Flat: 1>,..]

flats = flats.annotate(
    # type1_unpaid_amount=Sum(....),
    type2_unpaid_amount=Sum(Case(

        # If there is no debit which has debit_type=TYPE2
        # `flats` queryset return empty
        When(debits__debit_type__type=FlatDebitType.TYPE2, 
            then='debits__unpaid_amount'
        ),
        output_field=models.DecimalField(), 

        # I specified default value for getting 0 as value
        # if debits with TYPE1 but not affecting
        default=Decimal('0.00')
    )),
)
```

But if there is no debits which specified debit_type, queryset returns empty.

```
print(flats)
#<QuerySet []>
```

I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: `flats` is still `Flat.objects.all()`. If `flats` is empty, then you probably won't have any `Flat` objects in the database.

Comment: @FazilZaid I wrote this code for demonstration. So I forgot assing annotation queryset to `flats`.  I updated question.

Comment: what do you except it to return if the debit id is not matched?

Comment: @Exprator I expected to be each flat's `amount` field value `0` if debits with specified debit_type_id not exists on flat's debits.

Comment: Do you need to use when? Why not just filter and annotate the sum?

Comment: @YasinBahtiyar I have multiple calculations in the annotation same as `amount` and I want to get calculated values at once from db for performance(I wrote only `amount` for demonstration and not cause to confution).